# running dota 2 on nvidia optimus system

Tags: nvidia-optimus, steam, bumblebee

I have asus n56vb with geforce 740 m and I just installed ubuntu 13.10, bumblebee with proprietary nvidia 319 driver, steam and dota 2. I can succesfully launch steam without optirun and with "optirun -b primus", but can't launch it with just optirun - here is [console output.](http://pastebin.com/LUMnkzTW)

As I understand the main problem is

```
primus: fatal: failed to load any of the libraries: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1:/usr/lib32/nvidia-nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1: incorrect class ELF: ELFCLASS64
/usr/lib32/nvidia-nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1: unable to open shared object: No such file or catalogue
```

Then, if I open steam, I can launch dota 2, but I think it uses integrated video card (because I need to set all graphics options to minimal to get around ~40 fps). If I set "optirun -b primus %command%" or "optirun %command%" it doesn't launches at all.

So what should I do to make dota 2 execute on nvidia card?
Here is my [/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf](http://pastebin.com/urV9ix6G)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your bumblebee.conf file. In the line for the `LibraryPath` in the `[driver-nvidia]` section you have written,

```
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-nvidia-319-updates
```

whereas by default the library would be present in,

```
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates
```

Note the extra 'nvidia' in your line.